# Azure Python SDK ClientSecretCredential fetch the values from Azure keyvault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-automation, azure-python-sdk

Unable to get the values of tenant_id, client_id,client_secret which are stored in Azure Keyvault, by using library from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential. I have installed and imported the modules azure-keyvault-secrets azure-identity but for some reason its not working. i don't want to use import DefaultCredentials. Below is my python script

``````
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id='xxxxx',
    client_id='xxxxx',   ##the secret id's values should pick from Keyvault #
    client_secret='xxxxx'
)
subscription_id = "xxxxx"
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
`````
Assist me to solve this
``````

Comment: ClientSecretCredential expects you to give it the AAD tenant ID, an app registration client ID, and a client secret value that is added to the app registration. It does not fetch values from Key Vault.

Comment: yeah, i think you misunderstand how it works :) you need to provide those values and then you can use those credentials to access key vault to retrieve something. alternatively you can look at managed identities

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

> I agree with @junnas and 4c74356b41 comments   you misunderstand how it works :) you need to provide those values and then you can use those credentials to access the key vault to retrieve something

You need to use the **`Clientsecretcredential`** for authorization. you can use those credentials to retrieve the values.

Here is a sample of how it works:

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id='',#tenantid
    client_id='',#appid(clientid)   
    client_secret=''#app secret
)
client=SecretClient(vault_url="https://< Your vault name >.vault.azure.net/",credential=credential)
secret=client.get_secret("secret1")
print("The keyvault secret value:",secret.value)
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Reference:**
[Quickstart – Azure Key Vault Python client library – manage secrets | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-python?tabs=azure-cli)